# Executing a local exe file from flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I would like to run an .exe file from flutter web app and then use the generated output files for the web app. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea. Most, if not all, browsers **won't let you run an .exe** and I also think flutter doesn't allow that option. If you can give a context it would help to think of another solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).